# bxslider accessibility tabbing distorts slide alignment

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, bxslider

I'm using bxslider and have created 2 jsfiddles that show my problem.

We were have accessibility issues so I've upgraded the library to 4.2.3 which has better support

This is an example of bxslider and you can tab through the controls and everything is fine

http://jsfiddle.net/qax7w8vt/2/embedded/result/

The problem comes when there's a focusable element in one of the slides and when you tab through the content the slider alignment is distorted and never really recovers

http://jsfiddle.net/qax7w8vt/1/embedded/result/

[image]

Possible solutions...

1. tabindex=-1 on the "a" element but problem is that can't ever tab to the link
2. Listen out to a slide transition and somehow re-align the slider

I couldn't find a bug for this listed in their issue list so does anyone have a suggestion on how to handle this?

Better to check the fiddle but here's part of the source

```
<div style="width: 730px; position: relative; margin: 0 auto;">
    <ul class="bxslider">
        <li>
            <img src="http://bxslider.com/images/730_200/tree_root.jpg" title="Funky roots" />
        </li>
        <li><a href="http://google.com" style="position: absolute;left:200px; bottom:40px;">Some link here</a>
            <img src="http://bxslider.com/images/730_200/hill_road.jpg" title="The long and winding road" />
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="http://bxslider.com/images/730_200/trees.jpg" title="Happy trees" />
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

---

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.bxslider').bxSlider({
            slideWidth: 730,
            mode: 'horizontal',
        });
    });
```

Comment: what do you mean by "slider alignment is distorted" ? the fiddle looks fine..

Comment: Try pressing tab multiple times and you will see that the slider focuses on the "a" element and the slides are no longer aligned to the slider viewport

Comment: for tabindex="-1" will work only on html 5 and try hiding the element and only show it when it reaches there or slides in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know, maybe its a bug?

but, i can make a prevention using a `jquery focus listener`

```
$( "#prevent" ).focus(function() {
    slider.reloadSlider();
});
```

here the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qax7w8vt/3/

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, it led me to this solution - https://jsfiddle.net/c2ud095x/2/embedded/result/ - I disabled any focusable elements in the cloned slides and then did checks to see if the focused element was the same as the one the slider thought it was on. If not the same I would manually move the slider :)

Answer (score 0):

Try below code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('.bxslider').bxSlider({
            slideWidth: 730,
            mode: 'fade',
        });
});
```